# Solution of a system of linear equations $A^* x =0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are linearly independent. Let $A=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$, ${\rm rank}(A)=2$, then what is the general solution of $A^* x=0$ ?

I guess the answer is relevant to ${\rm rank}(A^* A)$, but I can not solve it.

Any hints are appreciated, thanks for your help.

---

Here, $A^*$ is the adjugate of $A$.

Comment: How it is possible that alpha_1 and alpha_2 are linearly indipendent if \mathhbb{R} is a one dimensional space? One of two must be zero

Comment: Sorry, I have edited.

Comment: What is $A^*x$? Do you simply mean the matrix-vector product $Ax$ or....?

Comment: Sorry, the "adjoint matrix" is the result of Google translation, not so accurate, now I find the answer: "In linear algebra, the adjugate, classical adjoint, or adjunct of a square matrix is the transpose of its cofactor matrix.[1]

The adjugate[2] has sometimes been called the "adjoint",[3] but today the "adjoint" of a matrix normally refers to its corresponding adjoint operator, which is its conjugate transpose."----wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

I think it should read $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3 \in \mathbb{R^3}.$

Then: $A^*x=0 \iff (y,A^*x)=0$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^3 \iff (Ay,x)=0$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^3 \iff x \in Im(A)^{\perp}$.

( $( \cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the usual inner product on $ \mathbb R^3.$)

Since $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are linearly independent and ${\rm rank}(A)=2$, we have $Im(A)= span \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I think that Im(A)=span(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)

Comment: Sorry, rank(A^*)=1, because A^* is the adjoint matrix of A, is it right?

Comment: W := {x \in \mathbb{R}^3: A^* x = 0} = span{alpha_1, alpha_2}^{\perp}, then dim W = 1, but rank(A^*) = 1, so dim W should equal to 2. ?

Answer (score 1):

$A^*x=0$ if and only if

$x^t A=(A^*x)=0$

but $A=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ so you have that

$x^t \alpha_1=0$

$x^t \alpha_2=0$

$x^t \alpha_3=0$

The first two condition tells us that

$x\in span(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)^\perp$

Viceversa if $x \in span(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)^\perp$  then $x$ satisfies the first two conditions but $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 $ are linearly indipendent and $rk(A)=2$ so it must be that $ \alpha_3\in span(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ then $x$ satisfies also the third condition.

To sum up

$\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 : A^*x=0\}=span(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)^\perp$

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you think A^* means? I think it is the adjoint matrix of A.

Comment: Sure, that is the traspost matrix of A, A^t

Comment: but I think traspost matrix and adjoint matrix is not the same thing.

Comment: When the filed is $\mathbb{R}$ they are the same thing

Comment: But adjoint matrix is the one that satisfies $A^*=|A|A^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry I don’t know that definition of adjoint matrix. For me  the adjoint matrix is the matrix associated to the adjoint operator of $F(x):=Ax$

Comment: Sorry, the "adjoint matrix" is the result of Google translation, not so accurate, now I find the answer: "In linear algebra, the adjugate, classical adjoint, or adjunct of a square matrix is the transpose of its cofactor matrix.[1] The adjugate[2] has sometimes been called the "adjoint",[3] but today the "adjoint" of a matrix normally refers to its corresponding adjoint operator, which is its conjugate transpose."----wikipedia –